# how can i solve this issue or how to install oci8.2.2.0 and a version of oracle instant client comptabile?

Tags: php, oracle, installation, oci8

i install the oracle instant client version12.2 on centos 8 but after i tried to install pecl install oci8-2.2.0  it's showing this error

> . -I/var/tmp/oci8 -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/var/tmp/pear-build-rooti0N33z/oci8-2.2.0/include -I/var/tmp/pear-build-rooti0N33z/oci8-2.2.0/main -I/var/tmp/oci8 -I/usr/include/php -I/usr/include/php/main -I/usr/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/Zend -I/usr/include/php/ext -I/usr/include/php/ext/date/lib  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -g -O2   -c /var/tmp/oci8/oci8.c -o oci8.lo
> libtool: compile:  cc -I. -I/var/tmp/oci8 -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/var/tmp/pear-build-rooti0N33z/oci8-2.2.0/include -I/var/tmp/pear-build-rooti0N33z/oci8-2.2.0/main -I/var/tmp/oci8 -I/usr/include/php -I/usr/include/php/main -I/usr/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/Zend -I/usr/include/php/ext -I/usr/include/php/ext/date/lib -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g -O2 -c /var/tmp/oci8/oci8.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/oci8.o
> In file included from /var/tmp/oci8/oci8.c:49:
> /var/tmp/oci8/php_oci8_int.h:58:10: fatal error: oci.h: No such file or directory
> #include <oci.h>
> ^~~~~~~
> compilation terminated.
> make: *** [Makefile:217: oci8.lo] Error 1
> ERROR: `make' failed

please some one can help  to solve this issue

i try to install with other version it's not working,it's only this version oci8-2.2.0 that available for php7.4

Comment: What exact pecl install syntax did you use?  Where did you install the Oracle Instant Client SDK header files (which has the oci.h file)?